# How to generate Excel form EPPluse which has group column header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable, export-to-excel, epplus, asp.net-4.5

I want to generate excel sheet from **EPPluse** which has group column header like below picture.Then How to build DataTable which handle this situation.  please help me to get it done easily.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have your tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Merge property on the ExcelRange object.

Here's an example:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Book1.xlsx")))
{
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"] ?? pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

    var rng = ws.Cells["BO1:BQ1"];
    rng.Merge = true;
    rng.Value = "Answer for Att 3";

    pck.Save();
}
```

You can use this code to write your group headers, then use ExcelRange's LoadFromDataTable() method to write your DataTable directly to the worksheet starting from cell A2